# Accessing .dat file from within a Jar file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to access a data file from a public class, both of which are located within a JAR file. However, when I execute the jar on a Hadoop cluster, the system throws a FileNotFoundException. The bottom line is: **is it possible to access resources within a Jar when running an application on a cluster, or does the resource need to be copied to the HDFS individually, and for either of the above, how would you go about implementing it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the JAR is in the CLASSPATH you can call `getResourceAsStream()` using a class loader or servlet context to get a reference to an InputStream for that file.

You will NOT have access to the file path.  You give a path relative to the CLASSPATH and the classloader finds the file.  You can get the contents, but not the absolute location.

You shouldn't want the absolute location.  What will you do with it?

You can't write to the file.  You can't alter anything.  If your app is packaged in a WAR file, you can't alter its contents.

Comment: So does InputStream pass the file path from within the JAR to the program as a string, or is it reading in the entire file as a stream, because I need the string for where the file is located.

Comment: That 'yes' is slightly confusing, since the OP actually asked two questions in 'either/or' format.  The rest of your answer is pretty clear though.

Comment: *"I need the string for where the file is located"*  1) It is not a file, but a resource inside an archive. 2) It is almost **never** a good idea to turn a `File` or `URL` object into a `String`.  Why do you think you need that?

Comment: The resource is being called by an API which locates the resource via a string.

Comment: *"The resource is being called by an API which locates the resource via a string."*  Bad API.  Bad, naughty API.  What does it then presume this String represents?  If it is a File and only a File, that complicates matters.  Does your application need this resource for **read only**, or is it necessary to also update/change the information (**read/write**).

Comment: I only need read only access to the resource; it's a database of values stored as a binary that the API is able to access.